# Story of Rabbi Who Burned Out His Eyes

Tags: sources-mekorot, rabbis, malach-angel, agada-stories-legends, tannaim

I once heard a story about a rabbi who was given a test by God, in which the Satan was sent in the form of a beautiful woman to entice him. He would not look at the Satan, and when pressed, he had one of his students bring him hot spits and he burned out his eyes.

God sent Refael to heal him, but he refused the boon unless he was promised that he would never again experience such a test. I think his demand was acquiesed.

Where is this the source for this story?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was R' Masya ben Charash. The *Tanchuma* (*Chukas*) relates the story you mention, except it says that he burned his eyes (he didn't stab them). The story is related in [the Hebrew Wikipedia article (fn. 14)](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%A9#cite_note-14).

Comment: Also yalkut shimoni 161! http://www.tsel.org/torah/yalkutsh/vayechi.html

Comment: Also midrash aseret hadibrot http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33203&st=&pgnum=29

Comment: Incidently, I can't find it in the tanchuma :/ but I found a sources that points to it other than the wiki article, which calls is a hosafa, addition, so maybe its not in all Tanhumas.

Comment: @BabySeal Interesting!